# Missing verb for a certain movement by hand

Tags: vocabulary

Supposing we are in a theatre, and a puppet show is on. What verb should be used to describe the movement by which that person on stage moves the puppet?

Here's what I am thinking of:

[image]

Comment: It may well be the case that no single word exists for "puppet moving hand motions". Is there a single word in your native language?

Comment: Being a Hungarian, I cannot think of a single verb which would clearly describe that movement. I can say things like "játszani a bábuval" (to play with the puppet), "megtáncoltatni a bábut" (to make the puppet dance) "húzogatni a bábut" (to keep pulling up and down the puppet) etc, but these are only vague descriptions, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puppets are the ones that are controlled by hands. Those controlled from above by a wire or string are called "marionette" and the one who controls marionettes is called "marionettist".

You could say:

> The marionettist **animates** / **controls** / **manipulates** the marionette from
>   above.

Comment: I like "animates". It's not the usual sense, but it works very well.